# How can i inherit properties from the css id rule to the css class?

Tags: css, inheritance

I have a css class rule:

```
.test{ text-align:center; font-family:Verdana; }
```

And i want to create another id rule (I hope It is right calling by "id rule" ):

```
#divNew1{ color: Red; }
#spanNew2{ color: Green; }
#pNew3{ color: Yellow; }
```

I have a lot of div elements. I want to pass .test class properties to other elements with only changing css file. That's why i don't want to add class attribute to div elements. The html code below:

```
<div id="divNew1">Ta ta taaaaa</div>
<span id="spanNew2">Ta ta taaaaa</span>
<p id="pNew3">Ta ta taaaaa</p>
```

But i want to add .test class properties to #divNew class by using inheritance and i don't want to add class attribute to the div like as above.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS is not a proper OOP language, and it is barely considered a programming language at all. You can't really apply the things you know from PHP or other languages to it. It really has a style all its own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just include the ID class on the upper declartion, the last declaration for any property wins. E.g. if the first rule had a `color: Green;`, `.test` would be green, `#divNew` would still be red.

```
.test, #divNew{ text-align:center; font-family:Verdana; }
#divNew{ color: Red; }
```

Comment: You know object oriented inheritence like that: "class NewClass : OldClass" or in java "class NewClass extends OldClass" . Is therey any way to do it like that?

Comment: You can't, you can make use of nested classes, for example <div class="test1 test2"></div> this will merge both style declarations to the div.

Comment: This the correct answer. Simply put, when you declare a new style, you can separate the list of items (classes or ID's) with a comma. If you want to override those attributes for just one of those items (in this case "#divNew"), you just need to re-declare another set of attributes for that item AFTER the initial declaration, exactly as per Nick's example. This supported even in legacy versions of MISE.

Comment: @uzay95 CSS just doesn't work that way, this is as close as it gets :)

Comment: The CSS paradigm is actually more flexible than J2EE style inheritance paradigm allows for, especially as you can can use selectors to change a style depending on parent elements, and element types, even based on parent element types+classes+ID's (at least, as long as the browser is better than MSIE 6).

Answer (score 4):

I believe the question is, can my "#divNew" CSS rule inherit the properties of the existing ".test" rule so that:

```
[Psuedo Code]

.test { color: red; }

#divNew : .test { border: 1px solid Black }
```

... results in an element with an id of #divNew getting both red text and a black border.

And the answer is no - there is no syntax for declaring the inheritance of one rule by another rule - but you can apply multiple CSS rules to one element.

In this example, the element would take the rules for "#divNew" and ".test" and ".another". It would override any conflicting properties with the last rule in your CSS.

```
<div id="#divNew" class="test another">...
```

Comment: kinda junk then right?   stuff like "material design" has a complex set of classes.   there are like 20 of those libs.   if i create a system using md, it's then wholly incompatible with another system.

Comment: @ErikAronesty CSS has a cascade, which is incredibly useful, though different from inheritance. There are some amazing things you can do if you embrace the cascade, or you can reject it an use something else that allows you to produce CSS in the way you want - the danger with the latter route is your small source file can produce highly bloated CSS due to repetition.

Answer (score 1):

LESS/dotLess allow you to perform additional processing within a CSS file on the server side, using a CSS style syntax. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). I'd link to dotLess, but I can't find a functioning link at present (http://www.dotlesscss.com/ is coming up empty for me)

*edit*

Or [T4CSS](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/02/t4-template-for-less-css.aspx) from Phil Haack

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by inheritance? If in your HTML #divNew is a child of .test, then CSS properties of .test are already inherited by it (unless you override them by setting specific #divNew properties).

Syntax for adding properties directly to #divNew which is also .test:

```
#divNew.test {/*properties*/}
```

Syntax for adding properties to #divNew which is a child of .test:

```
.test #divNew {/*properties*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divNew" class="test">Ta ta taaaaa</div>
```

Comment: But you didn't use inheritance to create id rule?

Comment: Sorry... right you are. Nick is right. In CSS the last style to be declared will be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand you, but:

```
.test{ text-align:center; font-family:Verdana; }
#divNew.test{ color: Red; }
```